# Adding a simple image

Tags: java, image, swing

I just want to add a simple image, but I get an `IOException` error.

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

I've been trying several different ways and all of them fail with errors.

```
private JRadioButton A = new JRadioButton("1");
private JRadioButton B = new JRadioButton("2");
private JRadioButton C = new JRadioButton("3");
private JRadioButton D = new JRadioButton("3");
private ImageIcon image;
private JLabel picLabel;



public Q2 ()// Constructor
{
super("Ait shit");


GridBagLayout GB = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints Col = new GridBagConstraints();
getContentPane().setLayout(GB);
Col.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
image = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("1.jpg"));





picLabel= new JLabel(image);
Col.gridx =0;
Col.gridy =0;
GB.setConstraints(A,Col);
getContentPane().add(A);
Col.gridx =0;
Col.gridy =-1;
GB.setConstraints(B,Col);   
getContentPane().add(B);
Col.gridx =0;
Col.gridy =-2;
GB.setConstraints(C,Col);   
getContentPane().add(C);
Col.gridx =3;
Col.gridy =3;
GB.setConstraints(picLabel,Col);    
getContentPane().add(picLabel);
setSize(400,320);
setVisible(true);




}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource().equals(4))
    {



    }

}



public static void main(String args[])
{
    Q2 a = new Q2 ();
}
```

}

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code, as well. Currently the indentation is inconsistent and there's a mountain of vertical whitespace. Additionally, please tell us *where* the error occurs, along with details of the other things you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: `BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("42.png"));` this line can `throw` and I don't see any `catch`ing.

Comment: The code won't compile due to the unhandled exception in the variable initialise block

Comment: I edited this question to make it easier for you to get a good quality answer; don't just make the question unreadable and basically spam again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why am I getting an `UnhandledIOExeption`?**

A quick look at your code reveals that you are trying to read from a `File` which may result in an `IOExeption` that must be handled. The line:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("42.png"));
```

`throws` an `IOException`.

From [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)):

> **public static BufferedImage read(File input)
>                             throws IOException**
>
> Returns a `BufferedImage` as the result of decoding a supplied File with an `ImageReader` chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The File is wrapped in an `ImageInputStream`. If no registered `ImageReader` claims to be able to read the resulting stream, `null` is returned.
>   The current cache settings from `getUseCacheand` `getCacheDirectory` will be used to control caching in the `ImageInputStream` that is created.
>
> Note that there is no read method that takes a filename as a `String;` use this method instead after creating a `File` from the filename.
>
> This method does not attempt to locate `ImageReaders` that can read directly from a `File;` that may be accomplished using `IIORegistry` and `ImageReaderSpi`.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> input - a `File` to read from.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a `BufferedImage` containing the decoded contents of the input, or `null`.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `IllegalArgumentException` - if input is `null`.
>
> `IOException` - if an error occurs during reading.

That means that you must handle the `IOExeption` by putting the line in a `try` `catch` block, like so:

```
try {
    BufferedImage myPicture  = ImageIO.read(new File("42.png"));
    // do stuff with myPicture  here
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle the exaption here
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another problem with this is that `myPicture` is only visible inside the `try` scope, so what you really should do is declare your variables at the class level and initialize them in the `Constractor` like:

```
private JRadioButton A;
private JRadioButton B;
private JRadioButton C;
private JRadioButton D;
private BufferedImage myPicture;
private JLabel picLabel;

// Constructor
public ExamPrac (){
    A = new JRadioButton("1");
    B = new JRadioButton("2");
    C = new JRadioButton("3");
    D = new JRadioButton("3");
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("42.png"));
        picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle the Exception here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // your other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it saying it can't read the input file but its in the source folder

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts the default dir where your program looks for files can be IDE dependent, If you are using Eclipse then it looks for the file in the Project dir not the src dir. to check for sure use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` that will return the working dir as `String`.

Comment: I put in the project dir,still nothing.Works occasionally.God I hate GUIs so much.

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts What do you mean by >works occasionally" ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Q2.<init>(Q2.java:40)
 at Q2.main(Q2.java:86)

Comment: It worked once,then I even deleted the image and kept working.So god dam annoying

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts This means that the `BufferedImage` you are passing to `new ImageIcon(BufferedImage)` is `null`.

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts Update your question with the changes you made in your code.

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts Don't  `new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("1.jpg"));` I wont go over it here if you want you can ask another question about it. just pass the path to the file like so `new ImageIcon("1.jpg");`

Comment: First time I think I ever had problem solved on stack overflow